# WordPress replace header.php from a plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have searched and cant find any answer.

How can I replace the themes **header.php** template from a custom plugin?

Everywhere I look it seems like it cant be done, and you can only change template parts from a theme/child theme.

But how does plugins like Elementor page builder do it then in their theme builder?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to include a custom header.php from my plugin. Because you can register templates like page.php, post.php or archive.php from a plugin via the [${type}_template hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/), I thought it shouldn't be that difficult to do the same for the header.php, but you can't load a custom header.php from directories other than parent or child theme's one.

When traversing down the `get_header` function you'll see the locate_template function being invoked to load the header template. But there is no way to hook into that function and to replace the path for the loaded header template:

```php
    function locate_template( $template_names, $load = false, $require_once = true, $args = array() ) {
        $located = '';
        foreach ( (array) $template_names as $template_name ) {
            if ( ! $template_name ) {
                continue;
            } 
            if ( file_exists( STYLESHEETPATH . '/' . $template_name ) ) {
                $located = STYLESHEETPATH . '/' . $template_name;
                break; 
            } elseif ( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $template_name ) ) {
                $located = TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $template_name;
                break;
            } elseif ( file_exists( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/' . $template_name ) ) {
                $located = ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/' . $template_name;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( $load && '' !== $located ) {
            load_template( $located, $require_once, $args );
        }

        return $located;
    }
```

One solution to bypass this limitation would be to get rid of the get_header function within your plugin's templates and to include the plugin's header.php via require or require_once statement from within the plugin's templates. But than you will have to implement your own get_header hook and locate_template functionality to enable replacement from the parent or child theme. See this answer for more information on limitations when omitting the get_header function:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5195/80177

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution

```
add_action('get_header', 'wpbet_replace_theme_header');

function wpbet_replace_theme_header(){

    require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/headers/header-padrao.php';

    $templates   = [];
    $templates[] = 'header.php';
    remove_all_actions( 'wp_head' );
    ob_start();
    locate_template( $templates, true );
    ob_get_clean();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Elementor does not replace the header.php. It adopts whatever header.php the active theme has. It simply takes over `the_content()` part.

`header.php` is essential part & asset of a theme.

You may build a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) with a different header (not different header.php)

Answer (score -1):

I have experience using a similar page-builder to elementor called site origin.

To the best of my knowledge wordpress page-builders don't manipulate or replace the themes template files. Instead, a lot of the page-builder content is displayed in the front end with [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) found in your template file. In addition, it appends a bunch of css and js scripts to the web page in order to handle the styling of the elements and interactivity.

As for your original question... If I understand correctly, there's no need for this plugin because the `header.php` file can be freely edited/replaced in the theme editor!

In the admin section, go to 'appearance' > 'editor'. Then under "theme files", select the template for header.php.

Comment: Until the theme comes out with an update and then your changes will get overwritten... If you create a child theme you can add your own header.php file to your child theme and then you don't have to worry about theme updates reverting your changes.